# Flutter android app err_unknown_url_scheme

Tags: android, flutter, url-launcher

on my Android Flutter app, I have the error "ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" when I try to open Facebook link with url_launcher.
On iOS, this works fine and open the page on a in-app web-browser.

Here my snippet code:

```
onTap: () async {
        final url = Uri.parse(urlDestination);
        try {
          if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
            await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
          } else {
            if (context.mounted) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: const Text(
                    'Impossible d\'ouvrir la page',
                  ),
                  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          // Error
        }
      },
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

I try to force add these lines in AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="fb" android:host="your_facebook_app_id" />
</intent-filter>
```